# Azure Workbook: How to link a Azure workbook to another by name?

Tags: azure

We are working on creating a custom connector to ingest the data in Azure Sentinel. We are now working on workbooks, and want to create a option of opening a new workbook, say secondary workbook, after clicking on Main workbook. But when we are trying to link the secondary workbook, on to the main, theirs just option of Entering static template ID of the second, but if we deploy the workbooks, the problem is the template ID of the workbooks is changing. Is their any way to keep the secondary workbooks template id constant, or linking the workbooks by name.

Can someone please help me determine how to link one workbook to another by name, or template ID of second, provided by keeping the second workbook's template id constant?